# Cambiar el orden de las palabras en oraciones subordinadas

Tags: sintaxis, subordinadas

¿Es posible invertir el orden de las palabras y construir frases tipo

> *Que haya terminado así* lo siento

o suena mal?

Comment: Aunque la distribución de las palabras en español es flexible, el orden que propones en ese ejemplo "suena" mal.

Comment: Si pones una coma queda bien. **Que haya terminado así, lo siento**

Comment: Para mí, suena algo extraño, pero no necesariamente mal, porque es correcto.

Comment: @DGaleano - ¿Se puede decir también *Que haya terminado así, siento*?

Comment: No hay que confundir lengua escrita y lengua hablada. La gente pone este "lo siento" al principio o al final de una frase.  Pero claro, al final como puso DGaleano, hace falta la coma.....y como no nativa, me sorpriende que los hispano hablantes no lo dicen... ¡ es una de las caracteristicas mas hermosas del español !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suena un poco raro, aunque no es un problema grave.

Queda mal, porque básicamente el "que" está para introducir una oración subordinada sustantiva y la oración subordinada que explica o modifica algo de la principal

> Siento **que** haya terminado así
>
> Lo siento - El qué? Qué sientes o lamentas?- Que haya terminado así.

Al cambiar el orden introduces  primero algo que explica o modifica la frase principal, que todavía no conoce tu interlocutor. Qué información le da a alguien "que haya terminado así"? No mucha. Estás hablando como el maestro Yoda de Star Wars, que era precisamente famoso por su su sintaxis.

Entendérsete se te entiende al final, pero es algo a evitar. Puede ser algo normal cuando estás hablando, porque lo mismo vas construyendo tus frases a la par que tu cerebro construye los razonamientos que quieres expresar, pero en el lenguaje escrito debería ser evitado.

En otros casos sí es posible (porque tenemos un uso distinto de subordinadas y de la partícula "que"):

> Es una pena que haya terminado así
>
> Que haya terminado así es una pena

Pero en este caso, supongo que al ser *sentir* un verbo transitivo (y tenemos entonces una subordinada sustantiva de complemento directo), queda **raro** que introduzcas primero el antencedente. Por ejemplo, en estas otras oraciones subordinadas sustantivas de complemento directo:

> Quiero que vengas  (suena bien)
>
> Que vengas quiero  (no suena del todo mal)
>
> No sé qué me dices (suena bien)
>
> Qué me dices no sé (suena raro y puede ser confuso)

Comment: Pero desde luego decir «dónde estará no sé» no me suena raro en absoluto.  Decir «que haya terminado así» primero puede ser más común si queremos enfocar en ello, o si todavía no sabemos qué decir.  Por ejemplo, hablando con alguien después de algo malo que le ocurrió, yo probablemente empezaría con algo parecido, «que haya terminado todo así, pues, es algo terrible/triste/una pena/etcétera».

Comment: muchísimas gracias, Diego =)

Comment: El español hablado suele cambiar el orden de las partes de une frase muy frecuentemente. Tambíen, la gramatica de una lengua hablada no es la gramatica de una lengua escrita o en escritura. Es lo que  cria su hermosura. También, hay repeticiones, que aclaran las intenciones del orador.